# Limit of $\lim_{x\to1} \frac{\sin{\ln {x}}}{x^5-7x^3+6}$

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

How does one evaluate this limit without using L'hopital's rule?

$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac{\sin{\ln {x}}}{x^5-7x^3+6}$$

I tried to use the substitution $u=\ln x$ but all I get is an exponential polynomial which can be factored, but it doesn't seem to lead me to a solution

Comment: The title says $\lim_{x\rightarrow 3}$ but the body says $\lim_{x\rightarrow 1}$. Which is it?

Comment: @JairTaylor Considering the limit is trivial at $x=3$, I assume the limit is supposed to go to $1$.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen That was my assumption as well.  But the OP should clarify.

Comment: Sorry the limit should go to 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$ \frac{\sin{\ln {x}}}{x^5-7x^3+6}=\frac{\sin{\ln(x)}}{\ln(x)}\times\frac{\ln(x)}{x-1}\times\dfrac{x-1}{ x^5-7x^3+6}$$
And $$x^5-7x^3+6= (x-1)(x^4+x^3-6x^2-6x-6)$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**
$$\lim_{x\to1} \frac{\sin{\ln {x}}}{x^5-7x^3+6}=\lim_{x\to1} \frac{\sin{\ln {x}}}{\ln x}\frac{\ln x}{x-1}\frac{x-1}{x^5-7x^3+6}$$